# ZSH: Run shell script from nodejs w/child process exec > command not found (beginner)

Tags: node.js, bash, zsh, child-process

I am trying to run a script from node w/exec and I get `/bin/sh: require_brew: command not found` in the terminal.
The goal is to run through a list of packages in node and then install them via a shell script.
The command I am trying to run looks like this `util/sh/requirers.sh && require_brew fzf`.

When I run only the command in the terminal it returns `zsh: command not found`.
I am not sure what do in order to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a single period `.` before the script like so:
`. util/sh/requirers.sh && require_brew`